# Chrome Extension: Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, manifest.json

I'm building a Chrome extension and using $.ajax (jsonp) to pull article titles and urls from a json array on a wordpress site.

If I GET from a https site, it works fine, however if I GET from a http site I get the following error.

```
Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
```

Unfortunately it's not possible in this instance to use HTTPS on this particular site, so how do I allow  a none http site in my Content Security Policy in my manifest.json or is it strictly https only?

Comment: Are you using ajax in your content script? If so, do it in the background script and send the results back via messaging.

Answer (score 1):

According to [developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), only HTTPS sites can be added to the CSP, not HTTP.

But you should not be doing JSONP from a Chrome extension, period. [Can't do HTTP Request with my Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030047/cant-do-http-request-with-my-chrome-extension)